# How can I extract multiple values from an XML column, using a function similar to value()?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery-sql

I'm trying to extract xml metadata from from SQL Server's Report Server Database. My current query is listed below:

```
SELECT 
 a.Name as 'ReportName'
,a.ReportXML
,Parameter = x.value('(Parameter/Name)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
FROM (SELECT C.Name,c.itemID,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),C.Parameter)) AS reportXML
      FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
      WHERE C.Content is not null
      and c.Type = 2 -- Report only
      ) a

cross apply reportXML.nodes('/Parameters') r (x)
WHERE 1=1 
and name ='ReportName'
```

My objective is to return all parameters associated with a report. The x.value method will only return 1 value at most. (It currently returns the first parameter of the report because 1 is hard coded in the string literal.) I know there are 5 parameters for the report I'm looking at.

Is there another function with similar syntax that will allow me to return all the values? Or is there a wildcard that I can use in place of the number? I've tried multiple functions on msdn with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is using `nodes('/Parameters')`. This will return a resultset with one row for each `Parameters` element - but there is only one probably.

With `Parameter = x.value('(Parameter/Name)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')` you are reading the first name of the first Parameter. If there are more `Parameter` elements nested within `Parameters` you will read only the first...

Without an example of your actual XML it is not easy to answer but:

Try to add one nesting level by adding this below your `cross apply`

```
outer apply r.x.nodes('Parameter') AS p (y)
```

Then change the column to

```
,Parameter = y.value('Name[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
```

This should read the first `Name` element **of each `Parameter` element**

If you need further help, please poste an example of your XML.

Btw: I do not understand this:

```
CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),C.Parameter)
```

What is the initial type of `C.Parameter`, that you have to cast it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and then to `XML`? If you are still using the deprecated `TEXT`, `NTEXT` or `IMAGE` you should consider to change this!

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked and you are also correct in inferring that C.Parameter is an NTEXT. It is because of this that I converted to varchar(max) and then to XML. Do you mind providing me the reason for changing this from NTEXT or pointing me to some documentation.

Comment: @SQLUser44, [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). NTEXT, TEXT and IMAGE where set to *deprecated* with SQL Server 2000 (!) already. Microsoft will end the support in one of the next versions. Today we use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)`. In your specific case you should use the datatype `XML`. This will 1) guarantee valid content and 2) speed up your queries, as you don't have to perform expensive casts of large types. Btw: Thx for the acceptance. It would be nice to vote me up also, thx!